Is there a way to sort out alphanumeric codes in Excel from a string with zero uniformity?
So I have a list of parts that have been ordered for the maintenance crew at my job. There is almost zero uniformity across different records. Some are just a string of 6 numbers, others have letters, commas, periods, slashes, and hyphens and can get up to even like 10 characters long. Here are a couple examples:
PH30-001 S/S bolt/nut for visible mounting
120.0V AC Power Supply for Static-Eliminating Bar  Part number:     2246K21
00118ET3E143TC-W2 AC MOTOR 1 H
G3083403,   Pilot Light,LED,120V,30mm,Chrome,GR
REPAIR ALLEN BRADLEY VPF-B1652C-PJ12AF SERVO MOTOR
128.980.006,   CONVERSION KIT FOR AXIAL FAN
CF-20TX-144 LEFT/RIGHT FOLDING ROD FOR T20CF
My job is essentially to extract the alphanumeric codes from these cells and put them in another column in excel. For instance:
PH30-001 S/S bolt/nut for visible mounting → PH30-001
120.0V AC Power Supply for Static-Eliminating Bar Part number: 2246K21 → 2246K21
00118ET3E143TC-W2 AC MOTOR 1 H → 00118ET3E143TC-W2
G3083403, Pilot Light,LED,120V,30mm,Chrome,GR → G3083403
REPAIR ALLEN BRADLEY VPF-B1652C-PJ12AF SERVO MOTOR → VPF-B1652C-PJ12AF
128.980.006,   CONVERSION KIT FOR AXIAL FAN → 128.980.006
CF-20TX-144 LEFT/RIGHT FOLDING ROD FOR T20CF → CF-20TX-144
Is there anyway to do this without manually copy and pasting or typing thousands of records?
I used the text to columns tool, delimited by all options, and got most part numbers separated out, but the only way I can see moving forward from this option is to just copy and past thousands of separated part numbers back into the main sheet. Any help would be appreciated.

So far it looks like you're looking for a word that is at least 7 characters long, has at least 5 digits, and the rest are uppercase alpha characters or a dash (minus). Look at your data more closely and try to fine-tune my broad observations. Then edit your question by adding this information.

It's likely any solution would require some level of manual validation to make sure there are no missed cases, or new cases in the future etc. You'd need to use VBA though.

Retrieve IDs From Column With No Uniformity

It is debatable if there is no uniformity. You'll have to prove it with some relevant sample data.
I used the space and some punctuation characters to split the words in each cell.
I used a minimum of 5 digits out of a minimum of 7 characters as the main conditions to retrieve the ID.
I didn't even bother to check if all characters are uppercase alpha-numeric, a period, or a dash. That's probably not too hard to implement.


=LET(data,B2:B11,min_length,7,min_digits,5,if_not_found,NA(),
        delimiters,{" ";",";":";";";"?";"!"},
    Digits0,SEQUENCE(10)-1,
    WordDigitsCount,LAMBDA(word,LET(
        s,--MID(word,SEQUENCE(LEN(word)),1),
        IFERROR(COUNT(TOCOL(XMATCH(s,Digits0),2)),))),
    DigitWordsToCol,LAMBDA(word_col,min_digits,
        DROP(REDUCE("",word_col,LAMBDA(rr,r,
        IF(WordDigitsCount(r)>=min_digits,VSTACK(rr,r),rr))),1)),
    r,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        s,TEXTSPLIT(r,,delimiters),
        f,FILTER(s,LEN(s)>=min_length),
        d,DigitWordsToCol(f,min_digits),
        IFERROR(TAKE(d,1),if_not_found)))),
    r)

The Lambdas (Name Manager)
   Digits0: =SEQUENCE(10)-1
   WordDigitsCount: =LAMBDA(word,LET(
       s,--MID(word,SEQUENCE(LEN(word)),1),
       IFERROR(COUNT(TOCOL(XMATCH(s,Digits0),2)),)))
   DigitWordsToCol: =LAMBDA(word_col,min_digits, 
       DROP(REDUCE("",word_col,LAMBDA(rr,r,
       IF(WordDigitsCount(r)>=min_digits,VSTACK(rr,r),rr))),1))


If you'd create the Lambda functions above, the formula could look like this:

=LET(data,B2:B11,min_length,7,min_digits,5,if_not_found,NA(),
        delimiters,{" ";",";":";";";"?";"!"},
    BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        s,TEXTSPLIT(r,,delimiters),
        f,FILTER(s,LEN(s)>=min_length),
        d,DigitWordsToCol(f,min_digits),
        IFERROR(TAKE(d,1),if_not_found)))))


Of course, you could easily convert it to another Lambda function.


This worked! I'm going to have to go through and double check everything because some have strings of numbers or letters too small or there are double strings, but this has saved a lot of time! Thank you!

Assuming your job can provide you with a master parts list, try the following in each part order row in column B:
=INDEX($C$53:$C$54,XMATCH("*"&C53&"*",$A$53:$A$55,2),1)

where column C is your parts list, column A is your parts orders.

Unfortunately, I have no list of anything other than the massive list containing all of the part combined with the part numbers like the above examples. So I would need something that entirely relies on the one column of the combined information to separate them out.

Any accounting or procurement department will have such a list and it should be easy for them to export it to an Excel file.

You could try going forward with parsing all strings in your orders list to a massive list that includes the part numbers along with extraneous strings. Delete duplicate rows and TRIM() spaces. This list might still serve your purposes but it would contain a lot of invalid strings. The formula might still work using your parsed list.
